# How to ask for data from another actor which is not ready yet?

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actorA that takes data from dataActor, and responds data to requestActors:

```
class A extends Actor {
  var data = Option.empty[Int]
  val requestors = mutable.Set[ActorRef]

  def receive = {
    case data: Int => 
      this.data = Some(data)
      requestors.foreach {_ ! data}
    case Request => 
      if (data.isEmpty) {
        requestors.add(sender)
        //What should I send back to sender here?
      } else {
        sender ! data.get
      }
  }
}
```

In the sender actor, I use the ask pattern:

```
(actorA ? Request()).map {
  //if the data is not ready here, how can I wait for data?
}
```

In the data provider actor, it sends the data to the actorA:

```
dataActor ! 100
```

The problem is the data may not be ready when the requestor is asking for it, so the Future from the ask may fail. I need to send the sender something to promise there is data, but apparently Akka does not seem to have promise AKAIK.

How to implement it here?

Comment: Why not reply with an explicit "DataNotReady" response? Then the requesting actor can decide how to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of possibilities.

First, you could return the actual `Option` (`data.get` is "code smell" anyway, and better be avoided):

```
 case Request() => data
```

And then just keep trying on the client end:

```
 def result: Future[Int] = (actor ? Request()).map { 
    case Some(n) => n
    case None => after(1 second, system.scheduler)(result)
 }
```

Alternatively, return a `Future`:

```
val ready = Promise[Int]()

case data: Int => 
   this.data = data
   ready.complete(data)
case Request() => 
   data.fold(ready.future)(Future.successful)
```

Now, you just need to flatten it on the caller side:

```
 val result: Future[Int] = (actor ? Request()).flatMap {
    case f: Future[Int] => f
 }
```

Comment: Thanks... I ended up using Promise. Let's see how it performs.